# Javascript sort array by shortest distance from number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort array elements in a way that element nearest to number should come first, and which are far should come last.

For example,

```
let arr = [1,16,14,13,6,7,4,5,3,2,19,20,10,4,6]
let number = 10

resultArray should be [10, 13, 7, 14, 6, 6, 5, 16,4, 4, 3, 2, 19, 1, 20];
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Pretty sure he means distance to the target number

Answer (score 5):

Sort by distance to `number`, where distance is the absolute difference between two numbers:

```js
let arr = [1,16,14,13,6,7,4,5,3,2,19,20,10,4,6]
let number = 10

const distance = (a, t) => Math.abs(t - a);
arr.sort((a, b) => distance(a, number) - distance(b, number));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `.sort()` method with `Math.abs`.

```js
let arr = [1, 16, 14, 13, 6, 7, 4, 5, 3, 2, 19, 20, 10, 4, 6]
let number = 10

let sortByShortestDistance = (arr, number) => arr.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a - number) - Math.abs(b - number))

console.log(sortByShortestDistance(arr, number))
```